# NumPy: unable to create 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading in data and trying to create a NumPy array of shape (175, 2).

I noticed that NUM.loadtxt (numpy.loadtxt) creates one dimensional array (175,). Input text file has 2 columns (ids, mean) as specified in the script but second column 'mean' is missing in the array.

I'm doing this:

```
import os
import numpy as NUM

datapath ="\\Projects\\prob\\2020\\data\\"
m1 = os.path.join(datapath, 'data.txt')
meanData = NUM.loadtxt(m1, dtype={'names': ('id', 'mean'), 'formats': ('S10', 'float64')},
meanData.shape
(175,)
```

Only first column 'id' available in the 'meanData' array. I want to bring second column 'mean' as well in the array.

How to create 2-dimensional (175,2) array reading data from text file?

I don't really have experience working with numpy specifically, any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably provide a sample of your file.

Comment: With a compound dtype like that the array is 1d with multiple `fields`.  Use field names, not column numbers to access them.  `meandata['mean']`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying to loop through id that failed to read idval (column 'mean'), index error.
  for ind, idVal in enumerate(ids):
       meanInd = NUM.where(meanData['id']==idVal)[0][0]
       meanVal = meanData['mean'][meanInd]
input data: 01613900,5.1084
01615000,34.2645
01616100,2.6952
01620500,15.2348
01621050,4.9419                                                                                                        
How to access first row and first column in for loop with a compound dtype?
Thanks for your insights!